# execute multiple threads on pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm trying to execute two concurrent processes, the first one calculates constantly (ex. every 0.1 seconds) the frequency recorded by the microphone, while the second one gets the frequency and paint a representation every 0.5 seconds.

I'm a little bit confused on how to implement threads, I'm not able to execute parallel threads.

Here a piece of code:

```
class MicrophoneThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MicrophoneThread , self).__init__()

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        print("Microphone Thread")
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)  
            self.emit(SIGNAL('listen()'))     


class PaintThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, el):
        super(PaintThread , self).__init__(el)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):           
        i = 0
        while True:
            i += 1               
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), str(i))
```

From the MainWindow I instantiate the threads.

```
    threadOne = MicrophoneThread(self)
    self.connect(threadOne , QtCore.SIGNAL('listen()') , self.listen, Qt.DirectConnection) 
    threadOne.start() 


    threadTwo = PaintThread(self)

    self.connect(threadTwo , QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)') , self.changeIndicatorAngle, Qt.DirectConnection)
    self.connect(threadTwo , QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)') , self.changeNoteLabel, Qt.QueuedConnection)        
    threadTwo.start()
```

Only MicrophoneThread starts, while the second one doesn't work.

Any suggestion or document to read is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by my self, the issue was so simple.

I instantiate the first Thread in the MainWindow when the program starts, while I instantiate the second one only when I click on a button on another form.

So I have a MainWindow in which I run the MicrophoneThread, and another one Form in which I run the PaintThread when I click on a button.